# Find values of keys in dictionary that contain a key word and return those keys and values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, search, words

I'm working on a function where I need to find values in a dictionary that contain a keyword and return them (only the ones with the keyword) along with their keys. I believe my code is on the right track.

Example Dictionary

```
{'M':[("One",1400,30.0, 20.5,"oil paint","Austria"),("Three",1430,100.0,102.0,"watercolor","France")],
        'P':[("Eight",1460, 225.0, 200.0, "fresco","Netherlands"),("Six",1465,81.0, 127.1, "tempera", "Netherlands")],
        'V':[("Four",1661, 148.0, 257.0,"oil paint", "Austria"),("Two",1630, 91.0, 77.0, "oil paint","USA")],
        'K':[("Five",1922,63.8,48.1,"watercolor","USA"),("Seven",1950,61.0,61.0,"acrylic paint","USA")],
        'C':[("Ten",1496,365.0,389.0,"tempera","Italy")],
        'U':[("Nine",1203,182.0, 957.0,"egg tempera","Italy"), ("Twelve",1200,76.2,101.6,"egg tempera","France")]
        }
```

So if I was searching for the keyword 'watercolor' the function should return this

```
find_keyword(dictionary2(),'watercolor')

{'M': [('Three', 1430, 100.0, 102.0,    
'watercolor', 'France')], 'K': [('Five',    
1922, 63.8, 48.1, 'watercolor', 'USA')]}
```

As you can see the function just searched for the keyword watercolor and returned the keys and values in the order that they appeared in the dictionary. I think my current code must be close but it is currently giving me an Assertion error and returning nothing every time. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Current code:

```
def find_keyword(dictionary,theword):
    keyword = {}
    for key, record_list in dictionary.items():
        for record in record_list:
            value = record[1]
            if theword in record:
                if key in keyword:
                    keyword[key].append(record)
                else:
                    keyword[key] = [record]
                    return keyword
```

Comment: "*An*" error is never enough information, see also [ask].

Comment: you use `keyword` in `find_keyword(..., keyword)` and later you overwrite it in `keyword = {}`

Comment: @furas Sorry about that I was changing some stuff around to make my code more clear hopefully my edit just now fixes it

Comment: always add full error message in question.

Comment: use `print()` to see what values you have in all variables. This can help you what is wrong.

Comment: you have wrong indention in `return keyword`

Comment: what is `db` in `find_keyword()` ? Better check names of all variables.

Comment: @furas I just fixed that and I just checked and this code is no longer producing any errors which is a step in the right direction

Comment: The position of the return keyword line doesn't seem to affect anything just tested in visualizer

Comment: why do you use `record[1]` ? shouldn't be `record[4]` ? As I said before - use `print()` to check values in variables.

Comment: I don't think so I thought record[1] was referring to the value I could be wrong I will try it with record[4]

Comment: do you want to seach only in 4th column or in all columns ? maybe you need `if theword in record` to check all columns. Or maybe `find_keyword(db, theword, column):` and `value = record[column]`

Comment: An extra parameter shouldn't be necessary I believe the current code does search through the entire dictionary I'm working on doing some tests and I'll get back to you with what happens when I print the values

Comment: So when I did the test and print it does still just print 'None'

Comment: @furas when I switched it to record[4] I'm now receiving a result

Comment: The problem now seems to be that the code only finds 1 value with the keyword and not all the values in the dictionary

Comment: if you want to search in all columns then use `if theword in record` or another loop `for col in range(5): if theword in record[col]`

Comment: @furas I edited my code above to include if theword in record but its still just returning one of the values where would I include this new loop?

Comment: because you have wrong indention in `return` - it leaves function after first result.

Comment: @furas You are a lifesaver I'm so happy that I managed to fix my original code it works perfectly now with your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use an `OrderedDict` since you want to return the first match in your `dict`.
- Your method has many unnecessary bells and whistles. Simply iterate thought your `dict`, search each key for your keyword, and return each key value pair that is a match.

---

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = {'M':[("One",1400,30.0, 20.5,"oil paint","Austria"),("Three",1430,100.0,102.0,"watercolor","France")],
     'P':[("Eight",1460, 225.0, 200.0, "fresco","Netherlands"),("Six",1465,81.0, 127.1, "tempera", "Netherlands")],
     'V':[("Four",1661, 148.0, 257.0,"oil paint", "Austria"),("Two",1630, 91.0, 77.0, "oil paint","USA")],
     'K':[("Five",1922,63.8,48.1,"watercolor","USA"),("Seven",1950,61.0,61.0,"acrylic paint","USA")],
     'C':[("Ten",1496,365.0,389.0,"tempera","Italy")],
     'U':[("Nine",1203,182.0, 957.0,"egg tempera","Italy"), ("Twelve",1200,76.2,101.6,"egg tempera","France")]}
d = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True))

# -------------- ########## ------------ #

def contains(seq, key):
     """
     Create A helper function to search for a key
     In a nested sequence of sequences.
     """
     return any(key in el for el in seq)

def find_key(d, key):
    """
    Iterate thought your `dict`, search each key for your keyword, and   
    return each key value pair that is a match.
    """
    tmp_dict ={}
    for k, v in d.items():
        for tup in v:
            if key in tup:
                tmp_dict[k] = tup
    return tmp_dict

print(find_key(d,'watercolor'))
```

**Output:**

```
{'M': ('Three', 1430, 100.0, 102.0, 'watercolor', 'France'),
 'K': ('Five', 1922, 63.8, 48.1, 'watercolor', 'USA')}
```